# How to redirect home page based on some criteria: PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to make my page redirect to different page based on the user type.
Below is my code, and it is not working.
Need help on fix it.

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($check);
                    switch($row["userType"])
                    {
                        case "Coordinator":
                        header("Location: staff_dashboard.php"); 
                        die();
                        break;
                        case "Lecturer":
                        header("Location: staff_dashboard.php"); 
                        die();
                        break;
                        case "Student":
                        header("Location: student_dashboard.php"); 
                        die();
                        break;
                    }
```

Comment: Did you checked `$row["userType"]` what is getting?

Comment: what is the error its throwing ??

Comment: First of all: Don't use `mysql_*`! Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead! Secondly, there can be several reasons. You're not using any error handling on the query. Something might go wrong there? It could be you're using headers while there's already output?

Comment: I think the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Echo the $row["userType"] and see what it outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you:-

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

switch($row["userType"])
                {
                    case "Coordinator":
                    header("Location: staff_dashboard.php"); 
                    die();
                    break;
                    case "Lecturer":
                    header("Location: staff_dashboard.php"); 
                    die();
                    break;
                    case "Student":
                    header("Location: student_dashboard.php"); 
                    die();
                    break;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see that you put 2 parameters in the mysql_query the first parameter should be your database conection then your query... Also look into using mysqli. The mysql is now deprecated.

EDIT: also use mysqli_fetch_assoc you can use mysqli_fetch_array but make sure your parameters look like this

```
mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
```